# Changing PHP variable outcome

Tags: php

I'm trying to display the name of the apple device model on my website

I'm currently using this PHP code to get the device model:

```
$device = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_MACHINE"];
echo $device;
```

this code gets the device model but display it as for example if i'm on an iPad 4 Wifi the result is iPad3.4 how can i change the displayed text in a way to replace "iPad3.4" with "iPad 4 WiFi" and "iPad3.5" with "iPad 4 GSM" etc...

Comment: Sorry but if you want to get this done yourself, you'll have to learn at least some PHP and in doing so you will very quickly figure this out all by yourself

Comment: Well i thought this is the right place to get help no matter if i'm pro in PHP or not, i'm not that null i can read and understand the use of code

Comment: It is. Still it doesn't replace a (more or less) thorough research of what you are trying to achieve - and as it is your problem is very common and you'll find many possible solutions shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should do the job, assuming you known most of values :

```
$deviceMapping = array(
    'iPad3.4' => 'iPad 4 WiFi',
    'iPad3.5' => 'iPad 4 GSM',
);

$device = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_MACHINE"];
if (isset($deviceMapping[$device])) {
    echo $deviceMapping[$device];
} else {
    echo "Unknown device";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

...If you want, you can do something like this:

```
$device = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_MACHINE"];

$conversions = array(
  'iPad3.4' => 'iPad 4 WiFi',
  'iPad3.5' => 'iPad 4 GSM',
);

if (isset($conversions[$device])) echo $conversions[$device];
```

Without knowing any PHP, this might be a little hard to get working correct, though. Feel free to try it, anyway.